# WP_Query не выводит записи на страницах категорий Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Вывожу в сайдбаре последние записи из рубрики Wordpress.

```
function last_news(){
$loop = new WP_Query('cat=722&posts_per_page=2');
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
while....
}else {
 echo __( 'Записей не найдено' );
}
wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Почему это не работает на страницах категорий Woocommerce? выводит - записей не найдено.

p.s. на страницах - записи, страницы, товары - функция работает корректно.

Comment: Код рабочий на первый взгляд. Или вы пытаетесь категорию товаров  WooCommerce вывести через cat=? Так там не категории, а таксономии.

Comment: Нет, вывожу записи,не работает именно только в категориях woocommerce, проверил шаблон, для вывода категорий Woo используется кастомный

Comment: Для вывода таксономии примерно так $query = new WP_Query( array( 'products' => 'flowers' ) );

Comment: Если код одинаковый, то ошибка в другом месте

Comment: Я бы проверил, добавив в WP_Query: post_type=post

Comment: post_type=post, не помогло, спасибо, проблема оказалась в коде который убирает товары не в наличии в конец списка.